# Embed type=application in html means?

Tags: html, applet, embed

Can someone please explain what does the following line of code exactly do? If I were to build my own Unity3D that exports a similar kind of applications for the browser, what should I do? E.g. should I register somewhere the type of these applications?

```
<embed type="application/vnd.unity" src="webplayer.unity3d">
```

This line belongs to this website http://unity3d.com/gallery/live-demos/index.html#bootcamp and is usually encountered for browser applications that have to use native computer resources. These apps are not Flash nor Javascript.

If I wanted to do that for my own software what process should I follow?

If someone could shed some light on that, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Still haven't figured out how to develop my own web player! Is it that hard or is it just uncommon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a MIME type indeed and for someone to use it for his or her own program a new MIME type should be registered which seems from the outside a long bureaucratic procedure. The way to do that can be found here: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2048.txt

Answer (score 1):

The `<embed>` tag is used for adding applets to a page and is [specific to Mozilla browsers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#embed).

The attributes of the tag depend on what exactly is being embedded (and because of this it's not included in HTML standards).  In a Java applet for example, the version of the JRE that supports the MIME type defined in `type` will be used to run your applet.

The `src` attribute indicates the location of a file located somewhere other than the webserver (for example, downloaded by the user as a plugin) that is needed to run your applet.

Essentially, the tag indicates that the embedded file is a Unity app and once the user installs the plugin, will require the Unity 3D web player to launch.  The link in the first part of this post has some examples for embedding Java apps (including how to do so and support other browsers), and the process is not dissimilar for other types of apps.

Comment: Thank you for that. Do you know how could I develop my own sort-of 'player' and prompt the users to download it if it's not installed already? This is not a browser plugin, is it?